# Why is this print statement firing infinitely?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

For this widget I'm initializing a listener for Firebase Realtime Database. The problem is that a print statement keeps firing infinitely in the section where I display the data at the node. Why is this?

Note - the `print` statement is firing infinitely but the `return Text('some msg')` only displays once. Does this mean I should just never print something in a StreamBuilder?

**Update: simplified the code below and added a comment on the line with the repeating print statement**

```
class ReceivedChats extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReceivedChats({Key? key, required this.groupID}) : super(key: key);
  final groupID;

  @override
  _ReceivedChatsState createState() => _ReceivedChatsState();
}

class _ReceivedChatsState extends State<ReceivedChats> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    await getChatListener();

    setState(() {

    });
  }

  Future<void> getChatListener() async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals
    final node = globals.groupChatsNode(widget.groupID);

    _groupChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(node);

    _chatsSubscription = _groupChatRef.onChildAdded.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      dataList = [];
      final data = event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

      dataList.add(data);

      setState(() {
        chats = dataList;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _chatsSubscription?.cancel();
    _chatsSubscription = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _rtdb.child('groups/' + widget.groupID + '/chats').orderByKey().limitToLast(25).onChildAdded,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print('##MyApp## receivedChats snapshot: ' + snapshot.data.toString()); //THIS PRINT STATEMENT IS FIRING MULTIPLE TIMES
                return Text('some msg');
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```